# Laravel Group inside Group Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm having a bit of a problem by using a middleware inside a group that has a middleware itself like the following code:

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang?}','middleware'=>'language'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
        Route::get('/login','AuthController@login');
        Route::post('/login','AuthController@do_login');
        Route::get('/logout','AuthController@logout');
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'checkout','middleware'=>'authentication'], function () {
           Route::get('/', "CheckoutController@step1");
    });
});
```

And my current AuthenticationMiddleware

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;
use Session;
use App;
use Redirect;
class AuthenticationMiddleware{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        die("inside");
        if(!User::check())
        {
            return Redirect::to("/login");
        }
        else
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: 
So, he enters this last middleware event when outside the /checkout scope. How can I avoid it ?
Thanks all

Comment: What problem do you have? Any error?

Comment: sorry, updated the description

Comment: Can you include your language middleware as well as your `app/Http/Kernel.php` too?

Comment: Can you give the an example of url you're trying to get?

Comment: i have the middleware defined on protected $middleware = [ .... 'App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware' and  on protected $routeMiddleware = [...
        'authentication' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware'
 ];

Comment: so the thing is that he enters authentication even when outside the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I see you added your middleware on both `$middleware` AND `$routeMiddleware`, thus the `AuthenticationMiddleware` will run on every request. If you only want your request to pass `AuthenticationMiddleware` on your specified route(s), then remove it from `$middleware` and only keep it in `$routeMiddleware`.

From the documentation:

> If you want a middleware to be run during every HTTP request to your
>   application, simply list the middleware class in the $middleware
>   property of your app/Http/Kernel.php class.

and:

> If you would like to assign middleware to specific routes, you should
>   first assign the middleware a short-hand key in your
>   app/Http/Kernel.php file. By default, the $routeMiddleware property of
>   this class contains entries for the middleware included with Laravel.
>   To add your own, simply append it to this list and assign it a key of
>   your choosing.